# Обрабатывать Контекст with

Tags: python, python-3.x, менеджер-контекста

Правильно ли в методе `__exit__` как-то взаимодействовать с `exc_type`? Делать какие действия, если ошибка определенного типа

```py
class Config:
    def __init__(self, block: int) -> None:
        self.__block = block
        
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.__block
            
    def destroy(self, suppress: bool):
        if suppress:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
            
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb) -> bool:
        flag = False
        
        if exc_type is not None:
            if exc_type is TypeError:
                flag = True
                
        self.destroy(suppress=flag)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Config((1920, 1080)) as b:
        b[0] = 1920
```

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что вы просто хотите подавить сообщения об ошибке? если так, что метод __exit__() должен просто вернуть True.  как и написано в документации: "If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a true value"

Comment: конечно правильно, https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#generator-decorator